# Error:Could not initialize class org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.DefaultToolingImplementationLoader

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After upgrading Android Studio to `v1.2.1` , this error appears :

> Error:Could not initialize class
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.DefaultToolingImplementationLoader

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this problem by removing the `android-studio/plugins/gradle` folder. And let android-studio to reinstall gradle afresh.